# Retrieving controller value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i have a temp data which i want to receive in javascript and then want to assign it to the tab selected? how would i do that?

```
var langid ="<% Tempdata["something"] %>";
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 'tabs' - langid);
```

Comment: Other then the obvious syntax errors, this should work. What's the error?

Comment: no my basic question is about the approach because nothing was coming in tempdata.

Comment: I see, sorry. I would use the approach you are using. Probably have the value on the model so I don't have to use "magic strings", but that depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `TempData` is what you would use to pass messages between controllers, so in your case `ViewData` is a better fit, even though it is considered a better practice to use a property of a strongly typed model. Despite the fact, that this will work:

```
var langid ="<%= ViewData["something"] %>";
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 'tabs' - langid);
```

inline `JavaScript` in your view is not a good practice either. And if you later want to extract this code into a separate js file, it will break. I would recommend creating a hidden field to store the value in the HTML, and read it with jQuery.

In your View:

```
<input type="hidden" id="yourLangId" value="<%= ViewData["something"] %>" />
```

In your js:

```
var langid = $("#yourLangId").val();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 'tabs' - langid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are missing a closing bracket.

```
var langid = <%: Tempdata["something"] %>;
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 'tabs' - langid);
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is for setting the tab text is though.

Answer (score 0):

another thing to notice is in second line

```
var langid = <%: Tempdata["something"] %>;
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 'tabs-' + langid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
alert('<%=TempData["something"] %>');
alert('<%=ViewData["someelse"]%>');
</script>
```

btw TempData uses Session, so probably you would like to stick with ViewData